# How to sort a nested dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

```
dict={"Student Id":{

                    "Name":"student name",

                     "tests":{"test1":["mark","grade","time"],

                              "test2":["mark","grade","time"],

                               "test3":[],

                               "test4":["mark","grade","time"]}}}
```

I want to sort this dictionary's "tests" to "test4" list to inside "test3" empty list and "test4" is empty list .

I tried to swap the values but if I add few more key value in "tests" how to sort?

```
dict={"Student Id":{

                    "Name":"student name",

                     "tests":{"test1":["mark","grade","time"],

                              "test2":["mark","grade","time"],

                               "test3":["mark","grade","time"],

                               "test4":[]}}}
```

After sorting this is what I expecting

Comment: Why is `tests` a dict at all? If there's no meaning to the names `test1` etc., it should be a list. And a list can be easily sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want empty lists to be ordered last and empty lists are falsey (of value 0), you can use `operator.not_` as a key function to sort the dict values so empty lists get a greater key value of 1, and zip the sorted values with the original keys for an update:

```
from operator import not_

tests = d['Student Id']['tests']
tests.update(zip(tests, sorted(tests.values(), key=not_)))
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVC7agMxEMStvmJRcyc4G_IoTMAfkCZNyuMIgl07h3OSkPYMjrkvSeMm-ah8TfRwcGMM3mpmZ2fZna8ft-d3a47H75HX8-XvDNfeDmAdec3WQz846xmM5TchEFZwkK88IhmGZ5RPcBAQS77ogSKT4aSZxJuiMQUOaTSju4haOWi_lQ3IjddICXAfDV1xnCs77m92PCTHZenx2rJpmoTI58ZHsa3On1ZdW2Wh6srAYnSomerP3tW50UCIQREWttjpj5FCrRrY0n6V4lNKCed7wzWqEvYp8__s_wA)

Answer (score 0):

Make each of test list as list and sort it.
and set sorted value into each tests.

```
dict =
 {
    "Student Id": {
        "Name": "student name",
        "tests": {
            "test1": ["mark", "grade", "time"],
            "test2": ["mark", "grade", "time"],
            "test3": [],
            "test4": ["mark", "grade", "time"],
        },
    }
}

tests = dict["Student Id"]["tests"]
values = list(tests.values())

values = sorted(values, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
# or
values.sort()
values.reverse()

for x, y in zip(tests, values):
    tests[x] = y
```